# How to redirect Python version to a file on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I don't know how to redirect `python --version` to a file on Windows.
If I enter `python --version >py_ver.txt` in the command prompt, I just get an empty py_ver.txt. But if I enter `python --help >py_help.txt`, I get all of the help written to the file.

Comment: Does `python --version` output anything to your console at all? Which version of Python did you install?

Comment: @eryksun, thank you for the editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python --version > version.txt 2>&1
```

This will redirect to the file `version.txt` in the directory you are running this command in.

The file will contain this:

```
Python 2.7.9
```

In Python 2, this information was sent to STDERR. It was [fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue18338) in Python 3.4

Comment: Hi @Andy, thank you for your help. Yes it's working, and I have tried <code>python --version 2> version.txt</code> also works. Ehm it's categorized as error?

Comment: Yes, it was in Python 2. It was [fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue18338) in 3.4

Comment: Btw, how can I write the block code? this is my first post and comment. haha. Oh yeah, actually I need to get python version from bat file but I am not familiar with bat file. Do you know how to do it? Thanks for one more time

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're running an older Python, `--version` was [added in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption--version). If you're running an older version of Python, you'll need to run `python -V` instead.

Comment: Hi @Cole, yes you are right. I need to use -V instead.

Comment: @yudychen Wait, did my approach work separately from or in addition to Andy's answer regarding STDERR? I'm not clear what the actual issue was.

Comment: the actual issue was I couldn't output python version to file. Based on Andy's answer, I need to redirect the error to file to get the python version